# How to display NSMutableAttributedString within ScrollView on iPhone

Tags: iphone, scrollview, nsattributedstring

I am developing an iPhone app and want to be able to use an NSMutableAttributedString inside a ScrollView.  Here are the steps I want to follow:

1. Grab a string from CoreData.
2. Copy the string into an NSMutableAttributedString.
3. Parse the string and modify the attributes of portions of the text.
4. Display the NSMutableAttributedString inside a ScrollView.

How can I do this?

If I am reading the docs correctly, only CoreText naitively supports display of attributed strings on the iPhone.  Is that correct?  If so, how can I create a CoreText object when I don't know how the Y value for the CGRect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon doing more research and experimentation, I found that there are methods available to calculate the size of the Rects used to draw CoreText.  I looked at the code from http://github.com/jonasschnelli/I7CoreTextExample as a starting point for my project.  Although there are a couple of bugs in the code, it does provide a good base understanding of how CoreText can be used.

By the way, although the code is set up to run on the iPad, the same code works on an iPhone.  I hope this helps someone.